# how crash a Podman container

Tags: kill, podman

I was testing the restart policy for my podman containers, for which i need to force a container fail. Stopping the containers won't help here.

I tried kill -9 but need process id for that using top i found pid

[da@DA-Ansible-RHEL-3 ~]$ sudo podman top admin
USER        PID         PPID        %CPU        ELAPSED             TTY         TIME        COMMAND
pwuser      1           0           0.000       1h21m54.33281495s   ?           0s          /bin/bash /run-service.sh
pwuser      34          1           0.000       1h21m47.332980952s  ?           0s          xargs java
pwuser      35          1           0.000       1h21m47.333109953s  ?           0s          tee logs/messages.log
pwuser      36          34          1.834       1h21m47.333160453s  ?           1m30s       java -ea -server -Dfile.

---

Now entered into container sudo podman exec -it admin bash
and kill -9 1 or 34 do nothing

podman ps still lists it as Up.